# Circumventing authentication by relative path in flask

Tags: authentication, directory-traversal

I'm working on a flask application which requires some authentication but not on every endpoint.
I use this piece of code to exclude certain endpoints from my authentication handler.

```
if request.path in NO_AUTH_PATHS or (re.match(r'/dashboard/.*', request.path) is not None):
        return None
```

I then though what would happen if i were to make a call to 
`https://<site_domain>/dashboard/../<restricted_path>`

Fortunately I got an authentication error, and I made the call both via my browser (Firefox 71.0) and through curl v7.67. This leads me to believe that `request.path` is parsed as  `/<restricted_path>` and not `/dashboard/../<restricted_path>`.

What I want to ask is where this parsing takes place? If it's done by curl and Firefox before forwarding the request, this method might be a huge security issue.

Comment: I've never heard of it done by user-agents (browser, curl), and the technique has been used to abuse badly configured sites. I suspect Flask is either "normalizing" the path before comparison (so `/aaa/../bbb` becomes `/bbb`) _or_ it flat-out rejects paths with `..` in them. **Note**: While `/dashboard/../restricted` is being caught, depending on how the regex and the rest of the app works, you _might_ find `/restricted/something/dashboard/` triggers the exclusion-from-authentication while allowing `/restricted/something` to deliver restricted content.

Comment: Thank you for your input.
Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this in a more secure way?

Comment: If `/restricted/something/dashboard/` "gets through" it will because it's finding `/dashboard`_somewhere_ in the path. You'd probably want something like `^/dashboard/` (where the `^` means "_at the beginning of the string_".

Comment: Why don't you use a library that handles all of this for you, such as Flask-Login? This way, you will avoid easy mistakes such as this.

Comment: Because the code isn't mine, I just began maintaining it recently. I looked into some authentication libraries but most don't really fit my use case and to implement them would probably require system wide changes.
Thank you for your input though :)